# Is there a fast way to find negative counterpart duplicates in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

Hi smart people of Stack Overflow,
I'm looking for a fast way to mark all pairs of rows in a 160,000 row Pandas Dataframe that are **each other's negative counterpart**.

Example Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a','b','c','b','c','d','b'],
                   'B': ['x','y','x','y','x','z','y'],
                   'C': [-1.23, 1.2, 9.8, -1.2, -9.8, 1.23, -1.2]})
```

Rows with indices 1 and 3 should be marked as a pair, and indices 2 and 4 as well. I'm strictly looking to match PAIRS, so for example index 6 should not get marked together with 1 and 3, and no index can get marked more than once.

The desired output should be:

```
pairlist = [1,3,2,4]
```

I've tried using itertuples() but it's slow:

```
pairlist = []
for row in df.itertuples():
    if row.C < 0 and row.Index not in pairlist:
        found = df.loc[(df['A'] == row.A) & (df['B'] == row.B) & (df['C'] == -1*row.C)].index.tolist()
        if len(found)>0:
            for f in found:
                if f not in pairlist:
                    pairlist.append(row.Index)
                    pairlist.append(f)
                    break
```

Any way to do this in a vectorized way?

Comment: Have you thought about sorting? (After sorting, the first matches with last, etc)

Answer (score 1):

For your case let do `transform` sum with `filter`

```
s=df.groupby(['A','B']).C.transform('sum').eq(0)
df=df[s]

df.groupby(['A','B']).groups.values()
Out[32]: dict_values([Int64Index([1, 3], dtype='int64'), Int64Index([2, 4], dtype='int64')])
```

Comment: apologies, I had not added row with index 6 to the original df. I just updated it, see OP.